# Is there a way to intentionally invoke lambda function multiple times using python script? How?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invoke

I used this for reference and my python script is as simple as one on this page https://www.sqlshack.com/calling-an-aws-lambda-function-from-another-lambda-function/

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  What are you trying to do, and what attack have you made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by using range and sleep function of python. So, I already knows that I can invoke lambda but I want to do it at least 5 times every 5minutes. So, I used range to repeat action 5 times and sleep to set 1minute interval per run.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke an AWS Lambda function programmatically via the [`invoke()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) command:

> Invokes a Lambda function. You can invoke a function synchronously (and wait for the response), or asynchronously.

The function can be passed a `payload`, which will be available to the Lambda function through the `event` parameter.